# how to set delegate to nil?

Tags: ios, facebook, delegates

my table view controller calls below in viewDidLoad

```
myFBRequest= [facebook requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/feed", myId] andDelegate:self];
```

and in dealloc,

```
if (myFBRequest) myFBRequest=nil;
```

I do that because if user clicks on back button, I wanna ignore the response that came or coming back.

however, I get the below error

*** -[FBRequest setDelegate:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x823e190

Why is that?  I thought I have to set delegate to nil if I dont' want the response anymore?

I'm so confused.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks,
Bec

Answer (score 0):

yes you can pass in `andDelegate:nil` if you don't want to response delegates.